# How to fix the items in my shop staying locked until both items individual if-statement requirements are met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I already have character selection down, but what I can't get working is the unlocking feature of my game's shop. My idea for how the player would unlock characters is that there is an invisible game object that will disappear once the player clicks on it with sufficient funds. This will then allow him to use the character because he has just unlocked it. My problem is that the 2 current game object locks I have are both not interactable until the player meets both of the if-statement requirements.

Also, the gold game object is a gold background behind the player that is supposed to go away after the character is purchased and owned.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Locked : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int totalScore;
    public Button locked;
    public Text totalscore;
    public GameObject gold;

    int wizNum;
    int snailNum;


    private void Start()
    {
        totalScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalScore", 0);
        wizNum = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("WizNum", 0);
        snailNum = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SnailNum", 0);

        if (wizNum == 1)
        {
            gold.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            locked.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (snailNum == 1)
        {
            gold.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            locked.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }


    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (totalScore >= 500 && wizNum == 0)
            locked.interactable = true;
        else
            locked.interactable = false;

        if (totalScore >= 1500 && snailNum == 0)
            locked.interactable = true;
        else
            locked.interactable = false;
    }

    public void BuyWizard()
    {
        totalScore -= 500;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TotalScore", totalScore);
        totalscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalScore", 0).ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("WizNum", 1);
        locked.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        gold.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void BuySnail()
    {
        totalScore -= 1500;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TotalScore", totalScore);
        totalscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalScore", 0).ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SnailNum", 1);
        locked.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        gold.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: So the character is locked by default (so set active to false in the editor) and `if (wizNum == 1 && snailNum == 1) { locked.gameObject.SetActive(true); etc. }`.

Comment: The question doesn't really describe the behaviour you are trying to accomplish. It just says "there is an invisible game object that will disappear once the player clicks on it with sufficient funds. This will then allow him to use the character because he has just unlocked it" but that doesn't explain what variable is the "invisible game object" or how much is "sufficient funds". basically we have to guess what those are referring to in the code

Comment: Also you are updating the `SnailNum` and `WizNum` in the PlayerPrefs but not in your class ... so they won't update until the next time `Start` is called so probably until you restart the app ....